# Almost surely vs expectation

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expectation

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3 \dots$ be a sequence of random variables.  In the limit as $i \rightarrow \infty$ we have 
$$
X_i \rightarrow 0  \text{          almost surely}
$$
Does it follow that In the limit as $i \rightarrow \infty$,
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_i) = 0
$$
where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes expectation?

On the otherhand let $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3 \dots$ be a sequence of random variables and in addition we have,
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y_i) = 0
$$
does it follow that in the limit as $i \rightarrow \infty$,
$$
Y_i \rightarrow 0 \text{ almost surely}
$$
I would love to see a proof or counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

1. The expectation of $X_i$ does not necessarily exist, but even if it does, 
   the sequence of expectations may not converge to $0$. For example consider a probability measure $\mathbb P$ on the set of positive integers such that $\mathbb P\{n\}= 2^{-n}$ (here $\Omega=\mathbb N\setminus\{ 0\}$). Define $X_i$ as $2^i\cdot\mathbb 1_{\{i\} }    $, that is, $X_i(\omega)=2^i$ if $\omega=i$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $X_i\to 0$ almost surely but $\mathbb E[X_i]=1$.

   We can modify the example in order to have $\mathbb E[X_i]=a$ where $a $ is a fixed number and we may even have $$\mathbb E[X_i]\to \infty$.
2. Take $Y_i=1$ with probability $1/2$ and $-1$ with the same probability.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with the notation in part 1 could you explain a little please.  Part 2 is great.

Comment: $X_i$ has value $i$ with probability $1/i$, otherwise zero.  In probability theory we do not use $\chi$ like this, instead $1_{(0,1/i)}$.

Comment: @Rob I've edited.

Comment: Also, in probability theory the term "characteristic function" has a different meaning.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I can't understand: your $X_i$'s are uniform random variables in $(0,1/i)$? Or are they constant random variables in $1/i$? Or do you mean precisely the r.v. $X_i : (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ given by $X_i(\omega)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1/i)}(\omega)$? I think all the three answers give a counterexample for OT's first question.

Comment: @aerdna91 I've edited.

Comment: Now it's perfect and way easier :)

Comment: Be wary: depending on the distribution of the $(X_i)$, they may not converge almost surely to $0$. That's not the case, for instance, if the $(X_i)$ are i.i.d., by Borel -Cantelli.

Comment: @D.Thomine You are right, I modified (again) the post.

Comment: Last version is very very nice. But could you (or D. Thomine) explain why the previous solution (with Bernoulli r.v.'s) didn't work?

Comment: @aerdna91 If $X_i$ are independent and $\mathbb P(X_i=i)=1/i$, $P(X_i=0)=1-1/i$, then by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, $P(\limsup_i\{ X_i=i\}=1$, hence we cannot have the almost sure convergence to $0$.

Comment: Ok, I can understand why $P(\limsup_i\{X_i=i\}) = 1$, but I can't see how this proves that the sequence doesn't converge a.s. to $0$. Would you mind to explain it to me, or maybe to give me any reference (even a proof in a book would be fine)? Thank you

Comment: @aerdna91 We got that for almost every $\omega$, there is an infinite subset $I(\omega)$ of the natural numbers such that for each $i\in I(\omega)$, $X_i(\omega)=i$.